# Delete from S3 bucket with Ruby SDK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to use the AWS SDK for Ruby to perform some S3 uploads, downloads, and deletes in a Rails application. Uploads and downloads are working just fine; deletes not so much. I have Googled endlessly and found several "solutions," but none of them actually work.

I tried several variants of Attempt #1. I tried delete_objects, tried passing in arrays and hashes instead of the single object name, tried passing in key: object name, etc.

Attempt #1:

```
def delete_file
  access_key_id = Rails.configuration.app['access_key_id']
  secret_access_key = Rails.configuration.app['secret_access_key']
  credentials = Aws::Credentials.new(access_key_id, secret_access_key)
  Aws.config[:credentials] = credentials
  s3_client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: Rails.configuration.app['s3_region'], credentials: credentials)
  s3_resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(client: s3_client)
  bucket = s3_resource.bucket(Rails.configuration.app['s3_bucket'])
  obj = s3_resource.bucket(Rails.configuration.app['s3_bucket']).object(object_name)
  s3_response = obj.delete
  Rails.logger.error("XXX")
  Rails.logger.error(s3_response)
  Rails.logger.error("XXX")
  return s3_response
end
```

Output:

```
XXX
#<struct Aws::S3::Types::DeleteObjectOutput delete_marker=true, version_id="null", request_charged=nil>
XXX
```

Attempt #2:

```
def delete_file
    access_key_id = Rails.configuration.app['access_key_id']
    secret_access_key = Rails.configuration.app['secret_access_key']
    credentials = Aws::Credentials.new(access_key_id, secret_access_key)
    Aws.config[:credentials] = credentials
    s3_client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: Rails.configuration.app['s3_region'], credentials: credentials)
    s3_resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(client: s3_client)
    bucket = s3_resource.bucket(Rails.configuration.app['s3_bucket'])
    s3_response = bucket.delete_objects({
      delete: {
        objects: [
          {
            key: object_name
          }
        ]
      }
    })
    Rails.logger.error("XXX")
    Rails.logger.error(s3_response)
    Rails.logger.error("XXX")
    return s3_response
end
```

Output:

```
XXX
#<struct Aws::S3::Types::DeleteObjectsOutput deleted=[#<struct Aws::S3::Types::DeletedObject key="[object_name]?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=[stuff]%2F20170813%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170813T164341Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=[stuff]", version_id=nil, delete_marker=true, delete_marker_version_id="null">], request_charged=nil, errors=[]>
XXX
```

Note that the S3 bucket I am using has versioning turned off, so there will only be one version of any uploaded file. I want to completely remove the given object name from the given bucket.

I'm looking for a programmatic way to do this in Rails 5.1. Thanks, all.

Edit: Two more attempts that don't work - same output as Attempt #1:

```
s3_response = s3_client.delete_object({
    bucket: Rails.configuration.app['s3_bucket'],
    key: object_name
})

s3_response = s3_client.delete_object({
    bucket: Rails.configuration.app['s3_bucket'],
    key: full_object_url
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you defining `object_name` in your code? Also,if you only need to interact with S3 buckets, I'd recommend you a much simpler gem: https://github.com/qoobaa/s3

Comment: The full URL path to the object is stored in an instance variable. I pull just the object name using: self.file_url.split('/')[-1] - I'll check out that gem and report back.

Comment: Reporting back. After refactoring to use that gem, deleting now works (and uploading and downloading didn't break). One issue with that gem is that the temporary download URLs don't reflect the content type for some reason, so files come down as binary whereas before they were images, PDFs, etc. I'll have to look into a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the much simpler gem: https://github.com/qoobaa/s3. Thanks to CV-Gate!